# How to clear textbox value using callouts in adempiere

Tags: adempiere

I have problem about callout in Adempiere. I have one callout in textfield, I want to clear the textbox value after executing the callout, the cursor will focus on the same textfield as we want Please help me! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this    `MTab.setValue(MClass.ColumnName, "");`

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it would make your answer even more helpful.

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score 0):

In callout you will get the mTab which is the object of current tab. Now you can access all the field of that tab using that mTab object.

So using MTab.setValue(MClass.ColumnName, ""); you can clear the textbox.
First parameter is column Name and second parameter is the value which you want to set.

Thanks